# typo3 login with c# webclient

Tags: c#, typo3, rsa, webclient

I need to do some web-scraping from a C# console application. The site is using typo3. I need some help to login, specifically at RSA encryption used by typo3 extension (/typo3/sysext/rsaauth/resources/jsbn/rsa.js). Any clues are appreciated. Here is the code:

public class TestTypo3Login
{

```
    public CookieAwareWebClient MyWebClient;
    public string TestLogin(String typo3Url, String userName, String password)
    {
        MyWebClient = new CookieAwareWebClient();

        var mozilaAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)";
        MyWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", mozilaAgent);

        // GET public key
        var rsaKey = MyWebClient.DownloadString(String.Format("{0}?eID=FrontendLoginRsaPublicKey", typo3Url));

        // sample public_key and exponent received from server
        // B712B54CCB46DB7DAB3564195CD387B0D054A680756EB434CF03A435C281A43746390CD82D57188F96B20F8BBCC60F6A6F89BE33856EDDB8F832E7CD412F96EF3651594EE84379FCE1D32E93732648A7B4218E411A0ADC8365204AAF0F71BD84FD47959381A95BBC51FD0FB44693CD8207C7D27DDA0CEF346126FBD5EC9238D9:10001

        var rsaParts = rsaKey.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string public_key = rsaParts[0];
        string exponent = rsaParts[1];
        
        //try to encrypt password in a similar way with javascript in /typo3/sysext/rsaauth/resources/jsbn/rsa.js

        var encryptedPassword = Encrypt(public_key, exponent, password);

        return encryptedPassword;

    }
    public static string Encrypt(string public_key, string exponent, string data)
    {
        var rsap = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters();
        rsap.Modulus = GetBytesFromHexString(public_key);
        rsap.Exponent = GetBytesFromHexString(exponent);
       
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); ;
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsap);        

        var res = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), true);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(res);
    }
    
    public static byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string hexString)
    {
        if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1) { hexString = "0" + hexString; }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the content of `public_key` and `exponent`?

Comment: I've made an edit with sample data. I still cannot get same result as JavaScript implementation.

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the original javascript typo3 fe_login code via an javascript engine.

Steps:

1. NuGet-Package Microsoft.ClearScript [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ClearScript/)
2. Capture following js files via Charles: base64.js, prng4.js, rng.js, jsbn.js, rsa.js
3. Add js files as resources to your project
4. Use following code:

   ```
       public string RsaEncryptPwJavaScript(string pw, string rsaPublicKey)
       {
       var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
       string resourcePrefix = "MyNamespace.Typo3Js";
       var keyParts = rsaPublicKey.Split(':');

       using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
       {
           engine.Execute("var navigator = { 'appName': 'Chrome' };");
           engine.Execute(GetResource(assembly, resourcePrefix + ".base64.js"));
           engine.Execute(GetResource(assembly, resourcePrefix + ".prng4.js"));
           engine.Execute(GetResource(assembly, resourcePrefix + ".rng.js"));
           engine.Execute(GetResource(assembly, resourcePrefix + ".jsbn.js"));
           engine.Execute(GetResource(assembly, resourcePrefix + ".rsa.js"));
           engine.Execute(GetEncryptJsCode());
           return engine.Script.encryptPw(pw, keyParts[0], keyParts[1]);
       }
       }
       private string GetEncryptJsCode()
       {
            //Code from Typo3 / fe_login.js - this.encryptPasswordAndSubmitForm
            return @"function encryptPw(pw, publicKeyModulus, exponent) {
           var rsa, encryptedPassword;
           rsa = new RSAKey();
           rsa.setPublic(publicKeyModulus, exponent);
           encryptedPassword = rsa.encrypt(pw);
           return 'rsa:' + hex2b64(encryptedPassword);
       }";
       }
       private string GetResource(Assembly assembly, string resourceName)
       {
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
   ```

The rsaPublicKey should be the string resolved by this call `var rsaKey = MyWebClient.DownloadString(String.Format("{0}?eID=FrontendLoginRsaPublicKey", typo3Url));`